# How do I properly style login/signup forms in django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

What is the correct way to have my own login forms in django-allauth?

1. Should I use `{{ form.as_p }}` and create my own `LoginForm` class? Where should I insert my HTML code then?
2. Should I not use `{{ form.as_p }}` at all and do my own HTML markup with every form field in my `signup.html` template?

Comment: I had this exact question. I would love to see more answers here or consensus that the only answer here (by Sapna Sharma) is correct

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own template for creating custom login page.

Below is login form I use, just basic template code.

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">


                     <h4>Login</h4>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.username|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Email" }}

                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
                     <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Password" }}                        
                    </div>                  


                    {% csrf_token %}
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success rounded btn">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    {% if form.errors %}
            <font color="red">Username or Password does not Match. Please try again.</font>
            <hr>

            {% endif %}


                </form>
```

Further for styling, I am using attr method through [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks).

Comment: It does not work out of the box. You need to create a custom template tag for "attr" to be recognized as a tag : https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/729/

Comment: @Nym1412  I get this error after trying your code along with your snippet ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @abicrazieeee In Sapna Sharma's answer, you need to replace ":" by "=" in the attr value. For example : {{form.username|attr:"class=form-control"|attr:"placeholder=Email"}}. See code example in snippet.

Comment: Need to mention for using attr, I am using widget_tweaks package.